# How to populate the data getting from loop ngFor on select a dropdown based on selected value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a div and select box. Initially I am populating all data on div using ngFor loop. Now I need to populate the data also based on selected option from select box. Suppose my selected value is 0, all data matched with 0,need to populate. I am already getting data using filter on select but how to populate in html using same variable(partnerContent) again, I am not getting. Here is code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6b8szk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  partnerContent: any;
  selectValChange;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.partnerContent = [
      {
        id: 1,
        status: 'one',
        type: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        status: 'two',
        type: 0
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        status: 'three',
        type: 1
      }
    ];
  }
  name = 'Angular';
  selected(selectedLevel: any) {
    console.log(selectedLevel);
    this.selectValChange = this.partnerContent.filter(function(el: any) {
      return el.type == selectedLevel.type;
    });
    console.log(this.selectValChange);
  }
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let cont of partnerContent">{{cont.status}}</div>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel" (change)="selected(selectedLevel)">
<option *ngFor="let content of partnerContent" [ngValue]="content">
{{content.type}}
</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly.

```
filteredPartnerContent: any[];
```

div is always bind to this "filtered" list

```
<div *ngFor="let cont of filteredPartnerContent">{{cont.status}}</div>
```

initially it will be equal to in `ngOnInit`

```
this.filteredPartnerContent = [...this.partnerContent];
```

when dropdown value changes then:

```
this.filteredPartnerContent = this.partnerContent.filter(function(el: any) {
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5xyab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**UPDATE**

To remove duplicates from a dropdown, first get only the types. This will result in an array of [0, 0, 1]

```
const types = this.partnerContent.map(x => x.type);
```

next filter out duplicates, there are many ways this one is "one-liner"

```
this.uniqueTypes = Array.from(new Set(types));
```

in HTML template:

```
  <option *ngFor="let type of uniqueTypes" [ngValue]="type">
    {{type}}
  </option>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bfdgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working perfect. Can we make same value of dropdown to populate once only, for example now 0 is populating twice , it should populate once in select

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER Sure, I updated my answer. Hope it helps.